How to add covariance data to gazebo sim imu message?
I am using Gazebo Sim Harmonic to simulate an IMU sensor on my robot. When I echo the IMU topic, I can see that the covariance fields of the messages are populated with all zeros. However, I would like to add nonzero covariance elements. In my custom gazebo system plugin, I subscribed to the imu topic, and am trying to modify the gz::msgs::imu to add covariance data. However, nowhere in the api do I see a function that can be used to modify covariance, like there is with the gz::msgs::pose_with_covariance class.
It seems odd that the covariance fields exist in the sensor message, but are not modifiable. Are imu covariances not supported yet in Gazebo Sim?

From a quick glance at the code, I conclude that the noise is read from the SDF file.
I did not find an example in the demo worlds repository, but you can refer to the SDFormat specification for the fields that should be implemented.

Thank you! I had looked at the sdfformat, but not closely enough. I was searching for covariance, but turns out its under velocity->noise.

Also for others seeing this, it is possible to set linear_acceleration and angular_velocity noise but not orientation noise. This is just because sdfformat doesn't specify a field for it.
